# ¿Cómo aplicar correctamente android:maxHeight en una CardView?

Tags: android

Estoy practicando el desarrollo de apps para Android y estoy haciendo una aplicación que muestra una lista de mascotas (en tarjetas) en un RecyclerView pero como todas las tarjetas llevan una foto en la parte superior esto provoca que algunas tarjetas queden enormes y otras muy pequeñas, no me molesta que los tamaños sean un poco variados pero algunas tarjetas tienen una altura excesiva, por esto quise usar `android:maxHeight` pero ya establecí diferentes medidas y no hay ningún cambio, la propiedad intenté aplicandola en la CardView y también solo en la ImageView de la foto pero en ninguno de los casos hay cambios.
También quiero hacer notar que no quiero que la imagen tenga un tamaño preestablecido, no quiero todas las tarjetas iguales, me parece bien que el tamaño de la tarjeta se defina por el de la imagen pero en algunos casos es demasiado, estoy usando `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` para que la imagen se recorte en caso de que no quepa en la tarjeta.

Entonces ¿Cómo podría aplicar la propiedad `android:maxHeight` o alguna otra propiedad para que las tarjetas tengan un tamaño máximo?

Mi código XML de la tarjeta es el siguiente, tiene la última prueba que hice con maxHeight en la CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cvMascota"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radio"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_entre_tarjetas"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/tarjeta"
android:maxHeight="500dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bone_on"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        <!-- Aquí también intenté usar maxHeight pero tampoco funcionó -->
        android:background="@color/blanco"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_datos_arriba"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bone_off"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nombre_mascota"
            android:textSize="@dimen/nombre"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_nombre_derecha"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFavs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_hueso_favs"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFavs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hueso_count"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la propiedad del cardview en el layout

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

por

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

no conosco tu adaptador, pero ahi deberia ser otro lugar en donde puedas definir el tamaño

Comment: Bueno mi idea no es que todas las tarjetas queden de un tamaño fijo, sino que pueda variar pero no exceda cierto tamaño, además poniendolo fijo con imágenes grandes no se ve toda la tarjeta porque la imagen abarca toda la altura y en imágenes pequeñas la parte de abajo (donde va el texto) se agranda dejando mucho espacio vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener diferentes tamaños con las `CardView` es importante que consideres el tamaño y **proporción** de la imagen que estás usando.

Además, cuando usamos ***cards***, se crean espacios en la parte superior ya que hay problemas debido al redondeado de la imagen. Para ellos puedes usar este método:

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Context context, Bitmap input, int pixels, int w, int h, boolean squareTL, boolean squareTR, boolean squareBL, boolean squareBR)
{
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    //make sure that our rounded corner is scaled appropriately
    final float roundPx = pixels * densityMultiplier;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    //draw rectangles over the corners we want to be square
    if (squareTL)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w / 2, h / 2, paint);
    }
    if (squareTR)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(w / 2, 0, w, h / 2, paint);
    }
    if (squareBL)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(0, h / 2, w / 2, h, paint);
    }
    if (squareBR)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(w / 2, h / 2, w, h, paint);
    }
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Para redondear los bordes superiores, debes mandarle `true` al método en los parámetros `boolean squareBL` y `boolean squareBR` con su respectivo `context` y `bitmap`.